# Is there any difference in the meaning of continued to fight and continued fighting?

Tags: gerunds, to-infinitive

I want to know the difference in the meaning of the two sentences below.

1. I continued to fight.
2. I continued fighting.

What is the difference in the meaning of the two sentences?
Please, let me know.

Comment: There is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning, only in tone and register.  "I continued to fight" has a more poetic, noble, and high class feeling to it, while "I continued fighting" is in a more common register.

Comment: thank you for your kind explanation